# Why std::chrono::day stored value is unspecified if d > 255

Tags: c++, literals, c++20, c++-chrono

Quoted from [std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""d](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d)

> A std::chrono::day storing d. If d > 255, the stored value is unspecified.

What is the rationale behind this limit ?

Comment: Why would you need to represent a month with more than 255 days? So the upper bound is reasonable. And 8 bits is a reasonable lower bound.

Comment: I wonder why it is specifically unspecified though for values over 255; unsigned integer overflow is a well-defined behaviour and the `255` makes it seem like it would be reasonably stored as an `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal can't store more than [`std::chrono::day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/day) itself can, which is `0`-`255`. This allows it to be implemented as a 1 byte data type, which as it usually will only store values between 1 and 31 is sufficient.

If you're looking for a data type to store a duration of an arbitrary number of days use [`std::chrono::days`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) instead.

Comment: Thanks!
I read the documentation too quick, I first thought that the new C++20 `chrono_literals::operator""d` literal was a `std::chrono::duration` like the C++14 `chrono_literals` ones...
I should have read [this page first](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).